# MongoDB cursor id 4017421524256 not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using a node mongodb module for all mongo database operations. but I am getting the following error: cursor id 4017421524256 not found. I don't know the reason for this error. and how to solve it

please help in this to fix this issue? and what is the reason for this issue?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: That error means you are attempting to perform some kind of operation on a cursor, but the mongod has no record of the cursor that operation is referencing.  That's about all we can tell without more details and/or some sample code.

Comment: I am using find query like:
return MongoDB.find(`test`, {uid:"123"}, {
            projection: {
                _id: 0
            }
        })

Comment: not using a cursor in above query @Joe

Comment: is any way to change cursor timeout so I can reproduce that issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `find` is implemented using a cursor

Comment: @Joe how I fix this issue in find Query?

Comment: We'll need more information.  The code that consumes the cursor that is returned from the find in your previous comment would be a place to start.  You will probably also need to look at the logs from the mongod that cover from the time the connection is established until the cursor not found to see if there is any information about that query there.

Comment: @Joe I am using find query.query looks like: await db.find({}).addCursorFlag("noCursorTimeout", true); but it gives me random curosr error

Answer (score -1):

the mongo server config error: cursor timeout;
check out [article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/#cursor.noCursorTimeout)